# Phase and magnitude of complex exponential transfer function

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following transfer function in discrete domain:

$$ H(z)=\frac{3z^2 +0.3z+0.1}{z^2 -1.5z+ 0.9} $$

I am asked to **compute the steady state response to a sine: $v[k] = \sin[0.6k]$.**

So based on my knowledge I would need to get the magnitude and the phase of $H(\mathrm{e}^{0.6j})$, in order to write the steady state as $y[k] = |H(\mathrm{e}^{0.6j})| \sin\left[0.6k + \angle H(\mathrm{e}^{0.6j})\right]$

My idea was to substitute Euler's formula for complex numbers $\mathrm{e}^{\theta j}= \cos\theta + j\sin\theta $ in the transfer function and then simplify it and manipulate it till I get a form like this $a+bj$. From this I would be able to compute the phase and magnitude.

My question is: is this correct? because I have tried to solve it many times, but I always get the same wrong result so I thought that the solutions were wrong but computing it on Matlab gives me the same result as the solutions. Can you spot what I am doing wrong?

NB.: This is my first time asking a question. I am of course not asking you to solve the problem, but more to give me a hint or solution on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: First note that your input signal $v[k]$ is in (discrete) time domain, and the transfer is defined in the frequency domain. You can obtain the output in frequency domain in a particular expression (that should be easier than the time-domain convolution). This is particularly useful because there is a known equalityfor the steady state response, that allows to compute it using either time-domain or frequency-domain representation.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean...